# How to generate dependency graph with text

Tags: graph, diagram, utilities

Is there a simple online tool that will generate a dependency graph (boxes linked by arrow lines) based on text input like:

A -> B

Much like this one:

[www.websequencediagrams.com](http://www.websequencediagrams.com)

(It generates a sequence diagram)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

[graphviz](https://www.graphviz.org/) is a tool for generating graphs.

[webgraphviz.com](http://www.webgraphviz.com) is a web app that uses graphviz, and lets you modify the text and display the corresponding graph (it has 5 samples/examples as well).

graphviz takes input like this:

```
digraph G {
   A->B
}
```

Answer (score 16):

http://www.nomnoml.com

It's using the syntax:

```
[A] -> [B]
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is really old, but it might help someone else later.

I personally like [yuml.me](https://yuml.me).

Given the following syntax:

```
[note: You can stick notes on diagrams too!{bg:cornsilk}],
[Customer]<>1-orders>[Order], 
[Order]++*-items>[LineItem], 
[Order]-1>[DeliveryMethod], 
[Order]*-products>[Product], 
[Category]<->[Product], 
[DeliveryMethod]^[National], 
[DeliveryMethod]^[International]
```

You can generate a rather complex diagram. And to facilitate it's use, this is all exposed as a series of simple URLs which you can embed in just about any web-based document.

- Edit Later - To come back and edit the image later: http://yuml.me/edit/5a963e1b
- PNG Image - For blogs, wikis or email. Transparent background: http://yuml.me/5a963e1b
- PDF Document - Great for printing. Infinite zoom.
- JPEG Image - Solid background. Plays nicer with some desktop tools.
- JSON File - To programatically save metadata.
- SVG Vector Graphics - Experimental

Answer (score 5):

- Go to this page: [Interactive GraphSource Demo](http://live.yworks.com/yfiles-for-html/1.2/demos/databinding/demo.yfiles.binding.interactivegraphsource/index.html)
- Switch the combobox above to "Dynamic Bindings"
- Enter these values in the fields

  - Nodes Source: `['Dummy']`
  - Edges Source: `['A->B', 'A->C', 'D->C', 'D->A']`
  - Lazy Node Definition: Checked
  - Source Node Binding:  `function(edge) { return /(.+)->(.+)/.exec(edge)[1];}`
  - Target Node Binding:  `function(edge) { return /(.+)->(.+)/.exec(edge)[2];}`
  - Leave the rest as is
- Hit the `New Graph` button
- Watch the animation and take a screenshot!

Answer (score 5):

Or you can use mermaid. https://mermaidjs.github.io/, which is available in Markdown interpreters, too.

Comment: Neat!  There seems to be an online version too: https://mermaidjs.github.io/mermaid-live-editor/